# Eclipse SWT: Browser#evaluate() always returns null

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I use SWT Browser object to load a web page like this:

```
Browser browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.BORDER);
browser.setUrl("http://localhost:18080/app/test-servlet");
```

I have a function to call the evaluate method. (The function is triggered by clicking a SWT Button on the control.)

```
public void evaluate() {
    Object content = browser.evaluate("getClientContent();");
    System.out.println("content: " + content);
}
```

On the web page, the javascript function getClientContent() is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getClientContent() {
        alert("test");
        return "test";
    }
</script>
```

When I click the test button on SWT application, I could see the alert box shown up with "test". But the evaluate() always returns null. What is wrong with the code? Thanks

Comment: Try using "return getClientContent();"

Answer (score 4):

You need to 'return' the result in the JavaScript, like this:

```
Object content = browser.evaluate("return getClientContent();");
```

Answer (score 0):

The return values are restricted to a few types:

> Returns the result, if any, of executing the specified script.
>
> Evaluates a script containing javascript commands in the context of
>   the current document. If document-defined functions or properties are
>   accessed by the script then this method should not be invoked until
>   the document has finished loading (ProgressListener.completed() gives
>   notification of this).
>
> If the script returns a value with a supported type then a java
>   representation of the value is returned. The supported javascript ->
>   java mappings are:
>
> *javascript null or undefined -> null
>
> *javascript > number -> java.lang.Double
>
> *javascript string -> java.lang.String
>
> *javascript boolean -> java.lang.Boolean
>
> *javascript array whose elements are all of supported types -> java.lang.Object[]

Try for example

```
 Object result = browser.evaluate("return 1;");
```

If the return type is not supported ... null seems to be returned.

Try for example

```
Object window = browser.evaluate("return window;");
```

The documentation for "evaluate" states

> An SWTException is thrown if the return value has an unsupported type, or 
>   if evaluating the script causes a javascript error to be thrown.

which I find misleading since I would expect the above line to throw an exception since the window object can not be returned.